# Events Not Showing Up in Properties Tab - VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I face a very different problem that I really don't get a clue on what to do. The events option(lightning option present in the properties tab) is not Showing Up in Properties Tab. Could anyone show me path in resolving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Go to --> View - Synchronize view. Then next goto split view you will see the events option available on the properties tab. This solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks. This is the only solution to this strange problem that worked for me. Even though I find now that I occasionally need to re 'synchronize views' in order to fix it, it's better than it not working at all. I don't know how many times I can write `object sender, EventArgs e` before I go crazy.